# Raising APIException in "update" Method of ModelSerializer does not Respond with Desired Status Code

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a field that should not be updatable, which I've found out `update` method on `ModelSerializer` is the best to do that. What I do, pretty much, is to:

```py
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if "content" in validated_data:
            raise APIException(
                _("whatever error message is"),
                status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,  # or plain int, 403
            )

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Oddly, the response's body is proper, which is:

```
{"detail":"whatever error message is"}
```

However, due to some unknown reason, it does not respond with status code `403`, instead it responds with `500`. `500` occurs when any exception is thrown during runtime in Django, yet the documentations of DRF clearly states that it especially handles `APIException` and responds accordingly. I do not know why it responds with `500`.

---

## Environment

- Python 3.7.4
- Django 2.2.7
- Django Rest Framework 3.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `code` argument to [`APIException.__init__`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8001087e9e335140b8063a23916d9c05b615acd4/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L103) is not a status code, but a mnemonic code which defaults to `"error"`.  If you want to change the status code, you have to create your own subclass [as suggested in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#apiexception).  Wasn't totally clear to me, either, until I looked at the code.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Thank you.